# when is the handler for boost::asio::async_read_until invoked?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, handler

I'm a novice at boost.

I'm testing boost async client. the reference code is as below.

http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_5_3/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp

the code is well done if `"Connection: close"` header value exists. but, `"handle_read_status_line"` handler was never invoked when I omitted `"Conneciton: close"` header in the HTTP request. 
(all handler for receiving HTTP response are invoked only when TCP connection is closed.)

In my opinion, `"handle_read_status_line"` should be invoked because HTTP response always include `"\\r\\n"` regardless of `"Connection"` header.

Could anybody explain to me when the handler for `async_read_until` is invoked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `async_read_until` returns when the `MatchCondition` has been met.

The sample assumes that the connection is per-request. It's pretty explicit in that:

```
  // Start reading remaining data until EOF.
  boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
      boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
      boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Comment: Mmm. I see your point about `async_read_until`. It _is_ being invoked for me though, without `Connection: close`

Comment: in your case, HTTP server might close TCP connection after sending HTTP response... I 've added the following code to trace in the entry point of the handler.  printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__); the result is as below. handle_connect
handle_write_request
Error: asio.misc:2

Comment: @user3315238 I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. Perhaps you should attach a SSCCE